# Can't Use DNS On Network Manager

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, nmcli

I followed [a guide by MakeUseOn setting a static IP on Ubuntu Server with Network Manager](https://www.makeuseof.com/configure-static-ip-address-settings-ubuntu-22-04/). After some time, my DNS has stopped working. I have tried using `sudo nmcli con mod static ipv4.dns "8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4"`. Using ping I can ping IP's such as 8.8.8.8, however if I try to `ping google.com`, I get the error `ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution`.

Edit: I realized this happened after I removed pihole in docker.

Edit 2: `nslookup google.com` resulted in the below result:

```
;; communications error to ::1#53: connection refused
;; communications error to ::1#53: connection refused
;; communications error to 127.0.0.1#53: connection refused
;; no servers could be reached
```

Comment: **DO NOT** simply delete your other post and recreate it fresh as you did.  This is a violation of policy, and "bumping" posts this way will result in your account being prevented from posting by the system if you do this enough.

Comment: @ThomasWard I reuploaded it to better show how I NetworkManager is not the default.

Comment: @mpboden This a server. `nmcli` is by the easiest way to set up a static IP so that is the method I used.

Comment: @Champe20 *actually* the simplest way to set up a Static IP on a server is netplan.  Network Manager can cause other confusion and problems.  Is there a *reason* you want to use Network Manager, or do you have an issue reverting to the *defaults* of `networkd` and `netplan`, which works better on servers?

Comment: @ThomasWard My netplan configuration kept on failing, however when I used nmcli, it worked without hassle. I recently lost DNS and am unable to figure out why.

Comment: @Champe20 your netplan configuration was probably failing because you had errors in indentation - an element which must be strictly followed in YAML. This is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You should go back and ask the original question, and provide ALL details, and then let us help you fix the netplan config files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I deleted pihole, systemd-resolv.service was disabled for an unknown reason. I fixed the issue by running the below set of commands:

```
sudo systemctl start systemd-resolved
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf 
# I then changed it from "nameserver 127.0.0.1" to "nameserver 1.1.1.1"
sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved
```

I was then able to use `ping google.com` perfectly fine.

Comment: I would like to add that sometimes the file /etc/resolv.conf  is no present and even in this case you can add the file and the nameserver (8.8.8.8). and it will work perfectly.